# Error en Json: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, tokens

estoy dando vueltas alrededor de este error hace dos dias, leí muchas preguntas que tienen el mismo error e intente implementar la mayoría de las respuestas correctas de las mismas pero no hay caso, ninguna me soluciono el problema... estoy queriendo mostrar un listado de contactos a través de Ajax y Php y me surge este este error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (contactos.js:17)
    at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

Probé haciendo un console.log(response) antes de parsearlo y resulta que personaid no esta definido pero si yo le coloco un valor (ej:47) en vez de "$_GET('personaid')" no me sale ningún error y funciona perfectamente, trae los datos y los acomoda en la tabla como debería de ser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      let personaid = $("#persoid").attr('personaid');
      console.log(personaid)
      listacontactos();


      function listacontactos() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/autoparts_system/modulos/contactos/lista.php",
          type: "GET",
          datatype: "json",
          data: {
            personaid: personaid
          },
          success: function(response) {
            let lista = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(lista);

            let template = '';

            if (lista.length != 0) {

              lista.forEach(lista => {
                template +=
                  `<tr>
                                <td>${lista.tipo_contacto_descripcion}</td>
                                <td>${lista.valor_contacto}</td>
                                                 
                            </tr>`
              });
              $("#listadoContacto").html(template);
            } else {
              $("#listado-head").hide();
              template = '¡No se han encontrado registros de contactos activos de la persona en la base de datos, agregue al menos uno!';
              $(".card-body").hmtl(template);
            }

          }
        });
      }
      });
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="persoid" personaid="<?php  echo $personaid; ?>">
    <div class="card-body text-danger">
      <table class="table " id="listado-head">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Tipo Contacto</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody id="listadoContacto">

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

este es lista.php

```
$personaid = $_GET['personaid'];
sql1="SELECT * FROM personas"
    . " INNER JOIN persona_contacto ON 
    personas.`persona_id`= persona_contacto.`rela_persona`"
    . " INNER JOIN tipo_contacto ON 
    persona_contacto.`rela_tipo_contacto`=tipo_contacto.`tipo_contacto_id`"
    . " WHERE persona_contacto.`estado`=1 
    AND personas.`persona_id`=".$personaid;

    
    $rs_con = $conexion->query($sql1) or die($conexion->error);

    

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_con)){
        $json[]= array(
            
            "tipo_contacto_descripcion" => $row['tipo_contacto_descripcion'],
            "valor_contacto" => $row['valor_contacto']
        );
    }
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes de `console.log(personaid);`?

Comment: Esa Línea era para comprobar que toma el atributo 'personaid' del tag<input> de  html, y si, lo obtengo... por consola me muestra el id de la persona seleccionada. tengo dudas sobre si tendré algún problema al enviar ese id a lista.php

Comment: No sé si es error al copiar aquí, pero estás usando paréntesis `$_GET('personaid')` en lugar de corchetes `$_GET['personaid']`

Comment: Si, si disculpas fue un error al copiarlo aquí. ahí le agregue al Php la Línea donde debería recibir desde Ajax el data:{personaid}

Comment: Como estás definiendo `datatype:"json"` no es necesario `JSON.parse()`, directamente la respuesta debe ser un objeto _JSON_. coloca `console.log(response);` y, al final de la función _success_ agrega: `, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { console.log(thrownError); }` para saber lo que está pasando.